# mysql Row aggregation with datetime column

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table as below. This table gets loaded into spotfire.
But since it has around 2 million rows , there are performance impacts.

I would like to write a sql to aggregate the rows from this table `JMS_STATS` and insert in to another table `JMS_STATS_AGGREGATE` so that count of rows gets reduced and still the counts of `queue_depth` and `queue_consumer_rate` column values are aggregated.

Can someone please help me with the aggregate query.

Here is my table

```
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| queue_name                   | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| queue_server_nm              | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| queue_slice_nbr              | int(2)       | YES  |     | -1      |                |
| queue_system_nm              | varchar(100) | YES  |     | SEP     |                |
| queue_env_nm                 | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| queue_depth                  | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| queue_inbound_rate           | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| queue_consume_rate           | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| queue_consumer_count         | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| queue_cluster_type           | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| queue_stats_collection_tmstp | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| id                           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Could you provide the output of the result you wanted for new table. provide the old table and new table with sample records

Comment: select aggregation columns,sum(queue_depth),sum(queue_consumer_rate from table group by aggregation columns ?